# how to try all possible combinations of password

Tags: passwords

know username of account for one site , and also know that password contains only numbers and length is 4, so maximum amount of combinations is 10k (10*10*10*10) need something (program or etc.) which will automatically try all of them and tell when it gets correct password and logs in. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you are expecting us to write some code for you. That is not how this site works. If you write some code to do this and you have a specific problem or question that you can't get answered elsewhere on this site you can ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with python,

```
i=0
fout=open('pwd.txt','w')
while(i<=9999):
    p=str(i).zfill(4)
    print p
    fout.write(p+'\n')
    i=i+1
fout.close
```

I've generated this txt [here](http://esads.epizy.com/pwd.txt?i=1).

And you can also attack on that site by using [python mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize).

ALso you can refer [this](https://coderinaero.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/brute-force-a-website-login-in-python/).